# Vert.x RouterBuilder.create for multiple open api spec

Tags: openapi, vert.x

I have multiple open api spec files and want to create a routerbuilder for each of them. Is it possible in vert.x to pass in a list of yml file url's in RouterBuilder.create.

e.g. Routerbuilder.create(vertx, List.of(url1, url2, url3));

```
RouterBuilder.create(this.vertx, List.of("petstore.yaml", "flowerstore.yaml"));
  .onSuccess(routerBuilder -> { 

  }).onFailure(cause -> { 
  startPromise.fail(cause);
})
```